# Record at sample rate lower than 44100 Hz : Audiokit, swift, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I would like to record audio files at a sample rate lower than 44100 Hz (ideally 8000 Hz). Is this possible with Audiokit? How could I do that?

The [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616523-setpreferredsamplerate) says that the sample rate typically ranges from 8000 through 48000 Hz (device dependant). I'm using a iPhone 5S.

I want to decrease the sample rate because I am doing some signal processing with vDSP. The computation time is too long with a rate of 44100 Hz.

When I try to set

```
    AKSettings.sampleRate = Double(22050) // I also tried with 16000, 8000
```

Before setting the session:

```
    do {
        try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
    } catch {
        AKLog("Could not set session category.")
    }
```

I can see in the logs that the AKNodeRecorder file duration is 5 seconds but it seems to record faster (the real time it goes from 0 second to 5 seconds is 2.5 seconds) :

```
   AKNodeRecorder: recording
   AKNodeRecorder writing (file duration: 0.1 seconds)
   AKNodeRecorder writing (file duration: 0.2 seconds)
   ...
   ...
   AKNodeRecorder writing (file duration: 5.0 seconds)
   updatePCMBuffer() read 110250 frames into buffer
```

Also, the output file has the sample rate and duration specified (22050 Hz and 5 seconds) but the values are all equal to 0.

I read [this post](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1009)  about this issue. I was wondering if there was an update and if the solution is still to proceed as ryanfrancesconi wrote:

1. Record audio file
2. Save it as .wav
3. Convert it with AKConverter with a new sample rate
4. Open the file
5. Do the signal processing

Thanks!

Comment: I believe Ryan's solution is still the most relevant.  Dave O'Neill, also on the core team, I think has some strategies in mind to deal with the sample rate issues, when he has time to address them.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but I've been hunting a similar solution for months and stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595444/avaudioengine-downsample-issue#) today. Look at the answer provided by @dengST30